# Python save dataframe with 31 million rows and 80 columns

Tags: python, pandas, csv, export-to-csv, pickle

Just now my program ran for 2 hours just at executing one line `df.to_csv()`, not yet completed. In the folder, where the file was getting saved, I see the `csv` file size regularly getting updated. After two hours, the file size was around 13 GB. Now, I stopped it.  I tried to save it using `pkl` it gave memory error. I am using Python 64 bit.

Any idea?

My code:

```
print(combined_csv.shape)
combined_csv.to_pickle( "%s.pkl"%(file_name))
```

Output:

```
(31535524, 85)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-68-2fe4b628f516>", line 1, in <module>
    combined_csv.to_pickle( "%s.pkl"%(file_name))

  File "C:\Users\..\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2593, in to_pickle
    protocol=protocol)

  File "C:\Users\..\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pickle.py", line 77, in to_pickle
    f.write(pkl.dumps(obj, protocol=protocol))

MemoryError
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to save this file?

Comment: Use `dask` library

Comment: @bigbounty I appreciate some examples or sample code on using `dask`

Comment: What's wrong with CSV in your case? Is it that it's taking a long time? Or the size of the file? If it is the time, unfortunately with data this large, it will take time to save a file to disk. If it is file size, you can compress your CSV with `combined_csv.to_csv("path.csv.gz"). If all of your data are numeric, then you could save to a numpy npz file.

Comment: you are refer https://dask.org/

Comment: @jakub Yes. I want to save the file. It is taking huge time. 2 hours, not yet completed. Yes! all numerical numbers.

Comment: There are other formats available such as hdf5, feather, parquet, msgpack. They may be faster and more compact. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html

Comment: How much RAM do you have? Could you be hitting a swap file often? If these are 8 byte integers then its about 24 Gig RAM. What about `combined_csv.dtypes`? If `object` they are python objects and taking up a lot more space.